# PHP mail function : Do I have to deactivate the firewall?

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

I'm making a mail sender with php in my localhost using xampp sendmail.

I configured the sendmail.ini and php.ini files as they should be, but I still get this error in the errol.log file :

> 19/04/18 13:51:58 : Socket Error # 10013Access denied.

When I searched I found that I have to deactivate the firewall, but I'm in a administration with controled firewall.

Any other solutions?

Configurations I made on sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_ssl=tls
auth_username= (my email)
auth_password= (my email's password)
force_sender= (my email)
hostname= localhost
```

Configurations I made on php.ini:

```
;SMTP = localhost
sendmail_path = C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe
```

Comment: Is your `smtp` port open?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa yes I did open smtp port (25) but still the same error.

Comment: Port 587:
This is the default mail submission port. When a mail client or server is submitting an email to be routed by a proper mail server, it should always use this port.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa should I change it from  sendmail.ini file?

Comment: Change it and try again https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa now I get this error > 19/04/18 14:36:26 : Connect timed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192056/discussion-between-allaeddine-khalid-and-andrei-lupuleasa).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the `mail()` (the default) and sendmail (with `isSendmail()`) transports in PHPMailer; use SMTP to localhost instead, as it's both faster and safer. It also means you can ignore all the mail and sendmail config in your php.ini. Try this:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
```

If you don't have a local mail server available (which would also explain why you're having trouble using `mail()`), change the `Host` property to point at your hosting provider's mail server instead - they should be able to provide documentation on the settings to use.

Answer (score 0):

Example with https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Enable `openssl`
In `php.ini` -  `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: I get this error:
2019-04-18 14:05:42 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

The link says that might be a firewall blocking, and I think that's the problem.

Comment: Do you have `openssl` activated ?

Comment: `echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";`

Comment: In `php.ini` -  `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: I uncommented that line in php.ini